# Update Missing Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, window-functions

I have a dataset that looks like the following

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      RowID          |     UserID       |      Code        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       1             |         123      |        0         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       2             |         123      |        0         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       3             |         123      |        50        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       4             |         456      |        0         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       5             |         456      |        100       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

I would like to update the 0s to the non 0 Code for each UserID.  Can someone provide assistance with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option uses an updateable common table expression and window functions:

```
with cte as (
    select code, max(code) over(partition by userID) max_code
    from mytable
)
update cte set code = max_code where code = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple sub-query for this:

```
update MyTable set
  /* If its possible that a user might have multiple Codes which are non-zero you adjust the sub-query to return the correct one */
  Code = (select top 1 Code from MyTable T2 where Code != 0 and T2.UserID = MyTable.UserId)
where Code = 0
```